# How do i measure redis replication delay?

Tags: replication, redis

Which of these can be considered  to monitor replication delay ? Redis_master_repl_offset, Redis_master_last_io_seconds_ago , Redis_slave_repl_offset

Comment: Please read the manual before asking questions.  http://redis.io/commands/INFO. (last_io) and http://redis.io/topics/replication (offset).

Comment: How can i say according to the above mentioned parameters that there is a delay ?

Comment: @Jeroen The given commands do not yield a replication-delay. What they do show is last-io-from-partner, which is not the same thing.

Comment: You can monitor the repl_backlog_active (manual is in the config http://download.redis.io/redis-stable/redis.conf)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Given results from an `INFO replication` command like this:

```
slave0:172.16.101.23,6380,online,424821
master_repl_offset:424827
```

You can tell that `slave0` is behind master by 6. This is the difference between the `master_repl_offset` and the offset value in the `slave0` line, which is the last number in it. If you have multiple slaves, each will get their own line with their own offset value.

Comment: What does value indicate ? What can be the threshold of a warning value ?

Comment: @karansindwani I believe the value there is `bytes`. I used small numbers here as an example, real ones would likely be very large. On our logstash redis instance, 1MB is a sign of pressure worthy of notice, but on an application-stack redis, even 20KB is considered slow. It depends, and only you can know what bad looks like.

Comment: For me the output looks like this `slave0:ip=10.0.1.162,port=6379,state=online,offset=925994074541,lag=0` so I'm looking at offset?

Comment: @radtek Yes, offset.